# Java - How does the String constructor convert the char array to String when there are numbers as arguments?

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor, default

I am confused as to how the Java String class default constructor converts the char array into String.

```
char c[]= {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'};
String s= new String (c, 0,3);
System.out.println(s) ;
```

Gives output as - HEL

In this case, the last character is taken as endIndex - 1.

```
char c[]= {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'};
String s= new String (c, 1,3);
System.out.println(s) ;
```

Gives output as - ELL

But, in this case, the last character is taken as endIndex only.

What's happening here?

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D,int,int)). It's not start index and end index, but start offset and length of characters to take.

Comment: Ooof, Was learning substring before this where it was start and endIndex - 1, so got confused with String constructor, but now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: maybe an additional test: `new String (c, 2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter is `count` not `endIndex`, it specifies how many characters are copied from the input. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D,int,int)):

> ```
> public String​(char[] value, int offset, int count)
> ```
>
> Allocates a new String that contains characters from a subarray of the character array argument. The offset argument is the index of the first character of the subarray *and the count argument specifies the length of the subarray*. The contents of the subarray are copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the newly created string. [emphasis mine]